# Send custom data to push notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic3

I see many types of data for displaying icon, and for custom sound etc, in push notification documentation. One of the example is like

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "It's a notification with custom payload!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "content-available" : 0         
    },
    "data" :{
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
    },
}
```

But how do I send this data? Can I send it through firebase console? I am using phonegap-plugin push for ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

**image**

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
title: 'The big survey',
text: 'Are you a fan of RB Leipzig?',
attachments: ['file://img/rb-leipzig.jpg'],\\image binding
actions: [
    { id: 'yes', title: 'Yes' },
    { id: 'no',  title: 'No' }
]
```

});

**small icon && large icon**

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
title: 'The Big Meeting',
text: '4:15 - 5:15 PM\nBig Conference Room',
smallIcon: 'res://calendar',
icon: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzfXKe6Yfjr6rCtR6cMPJB8CqMAYWECDtDqH-eMnerHHuXv9egrw'
```

});

[click here for official page](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)